# nodejs ES6 generator outputs only {}

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, generator

The following codes only output {} no matter what I do to my generator functions:

```
//test 1
function *myFunc(input) {
  //yield input;
  return input;
}
console.log(myFunc('dafuq happening')); //prints {}


//test 2
function *myFunc2() {
  console.log('wtf?');
}
myFunc2(); //prints {}
```

using nodeJS 5.10 on arch linux

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are ES6 generators and how can I use them in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18842105/1529630) or [What is “function*” in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9620586/1529630)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the function only return [an instance of Generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator), it doesn't run the content of the function yet. You have to call `next()` on the instance to start pulling the values:

```
//test 1
function *myFunc(input) {
  //yield input;
  return input;
}
console.log(myFunc('dafuq happening').next());
// prints { value: 'dafuq happening', done: true }

//test 2
function *myFunc2() {
  console.log('wtf?');
}
myFunc2().next();
// prints wtf?
```

Answer (score 0):

For controlling a flow of generator, I prefer (recommend) to use lib [co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co)

```html
var co = require('co');

co(myFunc())
.then(function(result){
    //Value, returned by generetor, on finish
})
.catch(function(error){
    //I recimmend always finish chain by catch. Or you can loose errors
    console.log(error);
})
```

And remember, that you have to yield only function, promise, generator, array, or object.